# I want to set Value of label from Class A - View to Class B - View in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, rcp

```
public class ImageViewer extends ViewPart {

    String text;

    public ImageViewer() {}

    public void setA(String val) {
        String text=val;    
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        Label labelMsg1 = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);  
        labelMsg1.setText("Hello"); 
    }

    public void setFocus() {}

}
```

I want `"Hello"` to be removed and a value `"val"` to be printed on my label. `"val"` is coming from a different view and is passed as a method. How can I do this?

Comment: What part of this is causing a problem? The code in the view, or how to find the view, or ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `setText` of your object, but it is only locally known. You need to make it a member and then you can do it:

```
public class ImageViewer extends ViewPart {

    String text;
    protected Label labelMsg1;

    public ImageViewer() {}

    public void setA(String val) {
        String text=val; 
        labelMsg1.setText(val);   
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        if (labelMsg1 == null) {
            labelMsg1 = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);  
            labelMsg1.setText("Hello");
        } 
    }

    public void setFocus() {}

}
```

Also, you want to set the text of your `Label` object, not its value.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value from a handler or other class you will need to find the existing view object (creating a new view object using `new ImageView` will not work).

Find the view using something like:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI..getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart view = page.findView("id of the view");

if (view != null) {
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view;

  imageView.setA("new text");
}
```

If the view has not yet been shown you can show it using:

```
IViewPart view = page.showView("id of the view");

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view;

imageView.setA("new text");
```